# CSS: Navbar field warp

Tags: css

I have my header page where I insert the menu as

```
<div id="app-header">
    <Collapse isOpen={menuOpen} navbar>
        <Nav id="header-tabs" className="ml-auto w-100" navbar>
            <EntitiesMenu />
            <AccountMenu />
        </Nav>
    </Collapse>
</div>
```

EntitiesMenu is:

```
return (
<Nav className="d-none-block ml-md-auto">
    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="/">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home" />{' '}
            Home
        </NavLink>
    </NavItem>
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>
            NumberPanel1
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu right style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel1" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel1();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel1
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel2" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel1();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel2
            </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="/NumberPanel2">NumberPanel2</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>
            NumberPanel3
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu right style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel3" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel3();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel1

            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel4" onClick={()=> {
                toggle();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel2
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel5" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel3();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel3
            </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="/NumberPanel3">NumberPanel3</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>
            NumberPanel4
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu left style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel4" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel4();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel1
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel5" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel4();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel2
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel6" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel4();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel3
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="/SubPanel7" onClick={()=> {
                togglePanel4();
                }}
                >
                SubPanel4
            </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="/NumberPanel5">NumberPanel5</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Account menu is:

```
<Nav className="d-none-block ml-md-auto">
    <NavDropdown icon="user" name="Account" id="account-menu" data-cy="accountMenu" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        {
        // show the field
        }
    </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

My problem is ( as it can be see in the image ) "NumberPanel5" goes at the head. While I would have the elements in the same row.

How can I do?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: This is not a `React.js` issue - this is a `CSS` issue.

Comment: You'll need to show us the css. Or at least mentioning that you want to do this with bootstrap only or your tooling of choice would be helpful.

Comment: @goto1 it also reactstrap component

Comment: @silencedogood the only CSS is write, I have use reactstrap component for Nav, Navbar...

Comment: @silencedogood maybe before I have not show a part. Now I have edited my question :)